# help me with a third question on beloved by toni morrison

Tags: meaning

Women stopped crying and danced; men sat down and cried; children danced, women laughed, children cried until, exhausted and **riven**, all and each lay about the Clearing damp and gasping for breath. In the silence that followed, Baby Suggs, holy, offered up to them her great big heart.

i know literal meaning of riven

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/riven

1. To rend or tear apart.
2. To break into pieces, as by a blow; cleave or split asunder.
3. To break or distress (the spirit, for example).

but it sounds odd to me to undestand it as To rend or tear apart.

can i see it as "spread over a wide area"? or are the really torn apart pieces?

Comment: You listed three senses, not just one. In this case, it's the third sense. Broken (from exhaustion).

Comment: thank you for the answer. could you explain the difference between exhausted and riven?

Comment: 1) riven is pretty rare, so you could replace it with 'broken' (but 'riven' is more poetic sounding) 2) 'riven' (or 'broken') is very metaphorical - think of it like a machine being 'broken down', unusable, barely working.

Comment: thank you for the answer mitch  it's a great help to me.